# PasswordRecovery and a MembershipPasswordException problem

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-membership, membership-provider, password-recovery

I have a PasswordRecovery control in my site.

I have my own customized class implementing MembershipProvider.

One of the methods is GetPassword, with username, answer as parameters.

it is activated when the user enters an answer for the question, and the method should check if the answer is correct.

as I understand, if the answer is incorrect, I should throw a MembershipPasswordException.

```
   throw new MembershipPasswordException("MyMessage");
```

when I go through it on debug mode, VS(2005...) gives me the following **Runtime Error**

**MembershipPasswordException was unhandled by user code**

but in the client side it seems like everything is working according to the plan, the user gets an error message saying the answer could not be verified.

So why do I get this error? is it ok anyway?

what am I doing wrong?

thanks

EDIT, this is the problematic code:

```
                conn = GetConnection();

            command = new SqlCommand("CustomMemProvider_GetPassword", conn);
            command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("ApplicationID", ApplicationID));
            command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("UserName", username));
            command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("Answer", Encrypt(answer)));
            SqlParameter pPassword = new SqlParameter("@Password", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 256);
            pPassword.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
            SqlParameter pStatusMessage = new SqlParameter("@StatusMessage", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 256);
            pStatusMessage.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;

            command.Parameters.Add(pPassword);
            command.Parameters.Add(pStatusMessage);
            command.ExecuteNonQuery();
            string passToDecrypt = Parse.ObjectToString(pPassword.Value);
            if (passToDecrypt == String.Empty)
                throw new MembershipPasswordException(Parse.ObjectToString(pStatusMessage.Value));
            else
                password = Decrypt(Parse.ObjectToString(passToDecrypt));
```

Comment: Can you show the code that checks the answer?

Comment: Ok, I edited the question with the code, as I said, at the Throw line the debugger says "unhandled exception" but on the client side everything seems ok... thanks

Comment: Sorry I didn't emphasize it... it's a Runtime error

Comment: I would try two things: one step through the code to ensure your SQL query is working correctly. Second, and this I'm not sure where to look, Check where that exception is caught. Sounds like it is "bubbling up" when it should be caught in the app. Sorry I can't be more help.

Comment: Could have something to do with [Break when exception is thrown](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d14azbfh.aspx/) feature.